# I am trying to write output of a python dataframe in a csv file.

Tags: python-3.7

I am getting an error on line 35 in the spamwriter.writerow() funtion. The error states that wRR should be byte instead of string. Please check the code given below:

```
import csv
import sys
import numpy as np
from numpy import genfromtxt
from numpy.linalg import inv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d, Axes3D

Lambda = float(sys.argv[1])
Sigma2 = float(sys.argv[2])

X_train = genfromtxt(sys.argv[3], delimiter=',')
y_train = genfromtxt(sys.argv[4], delimiter=',')
X_test = genfromtxt(sys.argv[5], delimiter=',')

# Get the number of columns -> dimension of the input vector -> size of identity_matrix
N = X_train.shape[0]
d = X_train.shape[1]
N_test = X_test.shape[0]

######################
##      PART 1      ##
######################

identity_matrix = np.identity(d)
LambdaDotIdentityMatrix = np.multiply(identity_matrix,Lambda)
XTransposeX = np.transpose(X_train).dot(X_train)
Inverse = inv(LambdaDotIdentityMatrix+XTransposeX)
XtransposeY = np.transpose(X_train).dot(y_train)
wRR = Inverse.dot(XtransposeY)

nameOfThePart1File = "wRR_"+str(int(Lambda))+".csv"
with open(nameOfThePart1File, 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='\n', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow(np.transpose(wRR))
```

Comment: So what is your question? The error message you stated is pretty obvious what the problem is...byte expected but string given.

Comment: Hi Capricorn, thanks for your response. Please understand that I am a beginner in python so it may be pretty obvious to you but not to me. From my understanding of the code the command 'wRR = Inverse.dot(XtransposeY)' inputs a matrix into wRR which is definately not a string. So why is error still prevailing?